# Comparing two rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

## Problem

I want to compare two rotation matrices $R_A$ and $R_B$ both representing the orientation of the same point cloud in space, but computed from different methods. The idea is to have an estimation of the error between those two matrices.

## Method

My idea was to do it as follows:

1. Compute the rotation $R_{AB}$ between $R_A$ and $R_B$ as $R_{AB} = R_A^TR_B$
2. Compute the axis-angle ($\omega$, $\theta$) representation of $R_{AB}$ using the following formula:
   $$Tr(R_A) = 1 + 2cos(\theta)$$
3. Use the angle $\theta$ as the rotation error.

In Python, I do:

```
r_oa = import(R_A) // See R_A below, in "Data"
r_ob = import(R_B) // See R_B below, in "Data"

r_oa_t = np.transpose(r_oa)
r_ab = r_oa_t * r_ob

np.rad2deg(np.arccos((np.trace(r_ab) - 1) / 2))
```

That seems quite straightforward to me, but I get $\theta = 23.86\unicode{xb0}$, which seems really unrealistic. This intuition is confirmed by the use of a software comparing the matrices, as described below in "Verification".

Am I doing something wrong there? Is it just not the right way to compare my matrices?

## Verification

In a processing software, I have the possibility to "compare" two matrices (each being a 4x4 matrix defining a position and an orientation: [R | t]).

The documentation does not explain exactly how it works, but the output of this comparison is:

- 4 values for the rotation [deg]: Omega, Phi, Kappa, Total
- 4 values for the translation: $\Delta$x, $\Delta$y, $\Delta$z, Total.

I assumed that the "Total" angle for the rotation is my $\theta$ (as described above). For the same matrices $R_A$ and $R_B$ as above, the software outputs: Total = 0.036477551. That seems much more realistic, but then I don't know why it is not what I get.

Just to check my computation of $\theta$, I tried to compute it on $R_A$ and $R_B$ (instead of $R_{AB}$) and to compare that to the output of the software when running its comparison between $R_A$ and $I$, and also between $R_B$ and $I$. Even though I don't get the exact same $\theta$ as the software, my result is really close (to the 4th decimal).

Assuming that the software loses precision somewhere, I believe that my computation of $\theta$ is correct. And my computation of $R_{AB}$ is quite straightforward, so I don't understand why I don't find the same $\theta$ for $R_{AB}$.

## Data

My matrices are:

$R_A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.956395958000000 & 0.292073230000000 & 0.000014880000000 \\
-0.292073218000000 & -0.956395931000000 & 0.000242173000000 \\
0.000084963000000 & 0.000227268000000 & 0.999999971000000\end{bmatrix}$

$R_B = \begin{bmatrix} 
-0.956227882000000 & 0.292623030000000 & -0.000013768000000 \\
-0.292623029000000 & -0.956227882000000 & -0.000029806000000 \\
-0.000021887000000 & -0.000024473000000 & 0.999999999000000
\end{bmatrix}$

The software outputs, for the comparison between $R_A$ and $R_B$: "Total = 0.036477551". Following my method, I get $\theta = 23.86$, which is completely different.

## Related questions

- ["Change in rotation" matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87338/change-in-rotation-matrix)

Comment: Don’t you have some documentation for this software that explains the values it produces?

Comment: There is some documentation, but not for that. At least not that I found =(. But one point is that I don't think it is realistic to have an angle of 23 degrees between both matrices. 0.03 seems much more reasonable!

Comment: Please show us how you get to this angle of $23.86°$. I don't think this is right.

Comment: In python, I do: `np.rad2deg(np.arccos((np.trace(r_ab) - 1) / 2))`, with `r_ab = r_oa_t * r_ob`, `r_oa_t = np.transpose(r_oa)`, `r_oa` = $R_A$ and `r_ob` = $R_B$ :-/.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I calculate $\arccos((Tr(R_{AB}) - 1)/2)$ in degrees using (`C++` and) the data cut-and-pasted from your post, I get $0.036455334$. Visually, as confirmation, the two matrices are all but identical when their rows are plotted as triples of vectors.) I don't speak Python, but don't see anything obviously wrong with the code in your preceding comment.

Comment: Octave ( `acos((trace(A'*B)-1)/2)*360/2/pi` ) gives 0.0364553343334292 degree, which is consistent with the answer from the C++ code in another comment. What is your Matlab code?

Comment: Wait... I have the same in MatLab actually. I had checked $\theta$ for $R_A$ and it was the same as from python, but apparently I had not checked for $R_AB$. Which would mean that my python computation of `r_ab` is wrong -_-.

Comment: But the way, it seems that `*` means array multiplication, not matrix multiplication in NumPy.

Comment: I just realized that. Sooo frustrating.

Comment: @JonesV: your are punished for blindly trusting your code and not checking intermediate results.

Comment: :-). I am new to scientific computations in python, but you're right. I won't forget that one, I guess!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you have mistaken array multiplication for matrix multiplication. In Octave, `acos((trace(A'*B)-1)/2)*360/2/pi` gives 0.0365 degree, but `acos((trace(A'.*B)-1)/2)*360/2/pi` (note it's `.*` here instead of `*`) gives 23.86 degrees.

In NumPy, `*` means array multiplication, not matrix multiplication. Your Python code seems to be incorrect.

Comment: And I was looking for an error in the maths =/.

Answer (score 3):

A direct way to measure the angle between matrices
is to view them as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$
and compute the cosine between these vectors as usual. Notation:
$\qquad x, y$ : 1d vectors
$\qquad A, B$ : $n \times n$ matrices
$\qquad A_{flat}, B_{flat}$ : the corresponding vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

$\qquad dot( x, y ) = \sum x_i y_i$
$\qquad \|x\| = \sqrt \, dot( x, x )$
$\qquad cos( x, y ) = {dot( x, y ) \over {\|x\| \, \|y\|}}$

$\qquad Fdot( x, y ) = dot( \, A_{flat}, \, B_{flat} \, ) = \sum \sum A_{ij} B_{ij}$
$\qquad \|A\|_F = \sqrt \, Fdot( A, A ) \ \ $
-- [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm)
$\qquad Fcos( A, B ) = {Fdot( \, A, \, B\, ) \over {\|A\|_F \, \|B\|_F}}$

Rotation matrices have $\|R\|_F = \sqrt n$ (check $\|I\|_F$),
so $Fcos( R, S ) = {1 \over n} Fdot( R, S )$.
($trace( A^T B )$ is also $\sum \sum A_{ij} B_{ij}$,
but your formula is missing the factor ${1 \over n}$.)

In python numpy, the same block of numbers can be viewed as a matrix (actually `ndarray`),
or as a 1d vector:

```
def cos( A, B ):
    """ comment cos between vectors or matrices """
    Aflat = A.reshape(-1)  # views
    Bflat = B.reshape(-1)
    return (np.dot( Aflat, Bflat )
        / max( norm(Aflat) * norm(Bflat), 1e-10 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach was correct. Here is my implementation in Python which works. It outputs the angle between two rotation matrices $Q$ and $P$.

```
def getAngle(P, Q):
    R = np.dot(P, Q.T)
    cos_theta = (np.trace(R)-1)/2
    return np.arccos(cos_theta) * (180/np.pi)
```

I took the math from this website, which is a good reference: http://www.boris-belousov.net/2016/12/01/quat-dist/

Comment: Nice code, it is better to clamp theta between [-1, 1] because it might be larger than 1 because of floating number calculation.